# Why JAVA BufferedReader can't receive String from python client after sending String using PrintWriter?

Tags: java, python, sockets, stream

I write codes that Python client sends String and JAVA server receives it and then JAVA server sends String and Python client receives it.

But I can't add code line that Python client sends String and JAVA server receives it again.

I use BufferedReader to get input stream and read it using readLine and utf-8. And I use PrintWriter to get output stream and send string but when I use BufferedReader after PrintWriter, I can't get String from python client.

Why JAVA BufferedReader can't receive String from python client after sending String using PrintWriter?

Belows are my codes.

JAVA server code:

```
package solution;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class sol {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8000);
            Socket socket = server.accept();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"
                    )
            );

            String a, b, c, d;

            a = br.readLine();
            b = br.readLine();
            c = br.readLine();

            System.out.println(a);
            System.out.println(b);
            System.out.println(c);

            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            pw.print("Hello");

            d = br.readLine(); // I can't receive? read? String from Python client..

            System.out.println(d);

            pw.close();
            br.close();
            socket.close();
            server.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Python client code:

```
from socket import *
from select import select

HOST = '' // sorry it is my ip
PORT = 8000

client = socket()

try:
    client.connect((HOST,PORT))

    client.sendall(bytes("A\nB\nC\n", encoding = 'utf8'))

    data = client.recv(1024)
    data = data.decode()
    print(data)

    client.send(bytes("D\n", encoding = 'utf8'))

    client.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `pw.println("Hello");`. If not, you need to flush the `PrintWriter` before the next read.

Comment: Oh my god.. you have saved my life!! thank you so much!! I really really really appreciate it

Comment: 1) From your comment in the code, I'm guessing you're not connecting over localhost. Have you checked that you can netcat between the two machines? 2) If you can netcat, did you check that on both sides of the system? That is, set up a netcat listener and make sure your py program can send to it, and similarly for the Java side?

Comment: Oh, it looks like you got your answer, good! :-) I'll keep my comment up though, cause I think it's good general advice on how to debug such a problem.

Comment: Thank you so much and I am sorry that I couldn't explain my problem clearly but I hope you know that I appreciate your help too !!